# What is dense layer?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm

I had a problem while training my dataset with LSTM and it was :

```
 Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (, 1) but got array with shape (, 0)
```

And after trying I've changed the dense layer units for 1 to 0 and it fixed my problem.
what is the job of this dense layer and what happens after changing it to 0 ?

reshaping the data set

```
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1))
```

the model :

```
regressor = Sequential()

#1
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True , input_shape = (x_train.shape[1],1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
#2
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
#3
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
#4
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(Dense(units = 0))

regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam' , loss = 'mean_squared_error')

regressor.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32)
```

I'm totally new to machine learning

Comment: Please show the rest of your model, and preferably the rest of your code.

Comment: You need to add a `Flatten()` layer after the 4th `Dropout` layer. Also, a `Dense` layer with `units=0` doesn't process any data since the output dimensions become 0.

Answer (score -1):

A dense layer is a Layer in which Each **Input Neuron** is connected to the **output Neuron**, like a Simple neural net, the parameters **units** just tells you the dimensionnality of your Output,

I think your problem comes from the dimension of the input data,
can you print out your input data dimension,
it should be **4D**